# Can I map IP addresses to allow 2 site to site VPNs with same IP range using Microsoft TMG

Tags: vpn, ip, site-to-site-vpn, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I have a Microsoft TMG server with a number of site-2-site VPNs which all have different IP address ranges.

Now a client has asked for another site-2-site VPN but their IP range clashes with an existing range.  Is it possible to set up some form of IP mapping so the two ranges can be used at the same time.

e.g. both clients use 192.168.0.x can I set it up so for one client we use the "real" ip addresses but for the other we use something like 192.168.1.x and TMG server changes it to 192.168.0.x and pushes it down the correct VPN.

Thanks.

Comment: In your example, how would TMG be able to tell which one the "real" IP was? If you can answer that, you can do it.